# I need Python 2.6 for a course but when I try to install it says there is nothing to install

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, python-2.6

When I try to install [python 2.6](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.6/) it says " The installer could not install the software because there was no software found to install". I need this Python for a class [Introduction to EE and CS 1](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-01sc-introduction-to-electrical-engineering-and-computer-science-i-spring-2011/software-and-tools/installing-the-6.01-software-on-macs/) and the modules don't work with any other python not even Python 2.7. I have like a week trying to solve this. I'm using macOS Sierra.

Note: I have previously installed Python 3.6

Comment: what operating system are you on? This is not the way to go about installing python.

Comment: What kind of class recommends an almost 10 years old version of software?  Avoid.

Comment: Try manually copying the package contents (assuming you're using Mac OSX)

Comment: @modesitt I'm using Sierra in macOS Sierra

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of python on mac were always a pain.  I doubt they have improved with age.  Get vitualBox, install an ubuntu image and work in a true linux environment.

Otherwise you need the mac dmg disk image download.

Comment: It'd be more beginner-friendly to spell [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) correctly and maybe provide a link to it.

Comment: @WombatPM I have kali linux in VBox and the course provides [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-01sc-introduction-to-electrical-engineering-and-computer-science-i-spring-2011/software-and-tools/installing-the-6.01-software-on-gnu-linux/) what I need to install in Linux. But I'm new to linux and I don't know how to install it there.

Comment: @JuanVicente you could get a debian package from [here](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python2.6) (Kali is debian based, afaik) you then install it via `sudo dpkg -i packageName.deb; sudo apt-get install -f` where *packageName* has to be replaced by the according name. The second part of the command resolves possible dependency issues.

Comment: @JuanVicente I saw that you also need numpy, so things can become more complicated. You actually might think about compiling from source as suggested on the page you linked. (also look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111012/installing-numpy-for-python-2-6))

Comment: @mikuszefski I will try that and give you my update!